# Running aide --check as a crontab job once a week

Tags: linux, bash, cron, cron-task, aide

I'm having real problems getting a simple (aide --check) job to run as a crontab job. I've tried everything I can think of but it won't seem to run. I've tried specifying the shell in crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

I've tried all kinds of variations of the command line:

```
*/1 * * * * root /bin/bash /usr/sbin/aide --check
*/1 * * * * /bin/bash /usr/sbin/aide --check
*/1 * * * * root /usr/sbin/aide --check
*/1 * * * * root /bin/bash /usr/sbin/aide --check >> /var/log/SystemFileCheck.log
```

Plus others but just can't get it to run.  I've followed online guides which all say I'm doing it correctly. I've tried putting it into a bash script instead and running that but no luck. What am I doing wrong?

These are some of the errors I'm getting:

Mar 30 11:25:01 localhost CROND[14060]: (root) CMD (root /bin/bash /usr/sbin/aide --check >> /var/log/SystemFileCheck.log)
Mar 30 11:25:01 localhost CROND[14058]: (root) CMDOUT (/bin/sh: root: command not found)

Mar 30 11:28:01 localhost CROND[14397]: (root) CMD (root /bin/SystemIntegCheck.sh >> /var/log/SystemFileCheck.log)
Mar 30 11:28:01 localhost CROND[14395]: (root) CMDOUT (/bin/bash: root: command not found)

Mar 30 11:39:01 localhost CROND[16094]: (root) CMD (/bin/bash /usr/sbin/aide --check)
Mar 30 11:39:01 localhost CROND[16092]: (root) CMDOUT (/usr/sbin/aide: /usr/sbin/aide: cannot execute binary file)

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance

PS. the once a minute is just for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user id can only be specified in the system crontab file. The entries of a user's crontab file don't take a user id. The entries in question are apparently found in a user's crontab file, which is why you get `root: command not found` from the first, third and fourth entries.

From the second, you get `cannot execute binary file` because you ask `bash` to execute `/usr/sbin/aide` as a bash script when it's not a bash script. You should be using

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/sbin/aide --check
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved the issue with your help. First off I was editing the user crontab when actually I should have been editing the system crontab.  I did get the user one to work but when I swapped back to the system one it still does what I need.  Thanks so much for your help.  Just need to also send the output to a second location now.

Comment: `*/1 * * * * /usr/sbin/aide --check >> /var/log/SystemFileCheck.log` should work just fine. You don't even need to set the `SHELL`  var because the command is a perfectly valid command for the default shell (`/bin/sh`)